# Handling Multiple Button Clicks in Android Recyclerview and storing response in Array or ArrayList

Tags: android, button, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am designing online quiz App. I have designed PlayQuiz.java file as below:

```
public class PlayQuiz extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DataBaseHelper database;
    private List<DmQuiz> quizList;
    private QuizAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_quiz);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_quiz_display);
        database= new DataBaseHelper(PlayQuiz.this);
        quizList= database.fillObjQuesList();
        adapter=new QuizAdapter(quizList,getApplicationContext());
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        });
    }

}
```

Now, this is my QuizAdapter.java file

```
    public class QuizAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuizAdapter.CustomViewHolder>{

        private List<DmQuiz>  questionList;
        private Context context;

        public QuizAdapter(List<DmQuiz> questionList, Context context) {
            this.questionList = questionList;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.quiz_display_format,parent,false);
            return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CustomViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            DmQuiz questionsList=questionList.get(position);

            holder.tvquestion.getLayoutParams().width= LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            holder.tvquestion.setText(questionsList.getQuestion());
            holder.optA.setText(questionsList.getOpta());
            holder.optB.setText(questionsList.getOptb());
            holder.optC.setText(questionsList.getOptc());
            holder.optD.setText(questionsList.getOptd());
            holder.optA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    holder.optA.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorButton));
                    holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);                 holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_unselected);     holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_unselected);                  holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_unselected);
                }
            });
holder.optB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

             holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_unselected);
                    holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
                    holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_unselected);
                    holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_unselected);



                }
            });
holder.optC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_unselected);
                    holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_unselected);
                    holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
                    holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_unselected);

                }
            });
holder.optD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_unselected);
                    holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_unselected);
                    holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_unselected);
                    holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);

                }
            });
holder.tvClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_unselected);
                    holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_unselected);
                    holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_unselected);
                    holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_unselected);

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return questionList.size();
        }

        public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            TextView tvquestion, tvClear;
            Button optA,optB,optC,optD;



            public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                tvquestion=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
                optA=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                optB=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
                optC=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
                optD=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
                tvClear=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvClear);


            }
        }
        public QuizAdapter(List<DmQuiz> questionList)
        {
            this.questionList=questionList;
        }
        public void setSearchOperation(List<DmQuiz> newList){
            questionList= new ArrayList<>();
            questionList.addAll(newList);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

Data in the Recyclerview is being displayed from SQLite database.

Now I want to handle/store the clicks on multiple buttons and send it to the remote MySql server. I am confused , how to store response for different questions ? Should I use ArrayList or something else, please help......

Answer (score 0):

In your `DmQuiz` model add a `questionId` and `selectedOption` fields which helps you to identify the proper answer to the question, then in `onBindViewHolder()` set the radio button against the selected option and make others unchecked. Also, add listeners to radio buttons which sets the `selectedOption` to `questionId`. Whenever you want to upload the quiz to the server, you can make a separate list by traversing the list as per the remote server requirements.

Refer DmQuiz model below..

```
class DmQuiz {
    //unique id per question
    int id;
    String question;
    String answer;
    String opta;
    String optb;
    String optc;
    String optd; 
}
```

In this, you can use `id` as a unique question id and `answer` as a selection i.e. "a"/"b"/"c"/"d" etc. , so after you just need to traverse through this `List<DmQuiz>` and create a `HashMap<String, String>` (or equavalent to maintain a (key=value) pairs ) just like ("id" => "answer").

Comment: Dear Sir, Thanks for the response. However, I am confused how I shall store the response for a particular question in a List ? e.g. For Q1, suppose a user opts for option 'C' and for Q2, he/she opts for option 'D' and Q3 is not attempted by the user and so on. Should I use 2d ArrayList of Integer or something else? Please help.

Comment: hi, please don't call me sir :-) ,, can you share DmQuiz model, so I can tell you the changes you can make.

Comment: DmQuiz model                                                                                   public class DmQuiz {
    int id;
    String question;
    String answer;
    String opta;
    String optb;
    String optc;
    String optd;
    

    ..........
}

Comment: I've updated the answer, please refer it. In case you need more help please ask.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you created a question with generic list of options, so quiz model would be like:

```
public class DmQuiz { 
    int id; 
    String question; 
    String answer; 
    int selectedOptionId;
    List<Options> options;
}
```

and option model would be like:

```
public class Option { 
    int id; 
    String option;
    boolean isSelected;
 }
```

After that you can create another recycler view inside each question item and populate the options, and each time the user click on one of the option, you can delegate those clicks back to the activity to handle the question with the new answer.